# Mootools - How to make a news slider (ticker) with arrows

Tags: javascript, slider, mootools, news-ticker

I'm developing a website using Mootools as Javascript framework.

I need to have some recent news circulating in a horizontal news ticker on the top of the page. I want to have 4 or 5 different pieces of news (among a total of 20) visbile at the same time and rotating.

I found the following clean script:

```
/* ImageSlider
* version 0.1 *
* Copyright (c) 2008-2010 ecce media Ltd (www.eccemedia.com) *
     * http://www.eccemedia.com/blog/blog.html&blogid=5 *
     */


    var ImageSlider = new Class({
        Implements: [Options],
        options: {
            sliders: 'slider-list',
            transitionduration:5000,
            autorotate:true,
            transition:Fx.Transitions.linear
        },
        initialize: function(options) {
            this.setOptions(options);
            var c = this;
            var op = this.options;
            if(op.autorotate) this.animate();
            $(op.sliders).addEvent('mouseover',function(){op.SlideFX.pause();});
            $(op.sliders).addEvent('mouseleave',function(){op.SlideFX.resume();});

        },
        animate:function(){
            var c = this;
            var op = this.options;
            var sliders = $$('#'+op.sliders+' li');
            if(sliders.length>0){
                op.SlideFX = new Fx.Tween(sliders[0],{'transition':op.transition,'duration':op.transitionduration,'onComplete':function(){
                    sliders[0].inject($(op.sliders));
                    sliders[0].setStyle('margin-left',0);
                    c.animate();
                }});
                op.SlideFX.start('margin-left', -sliders[0].getSize().x);
            }
        }
    });

var sliderID = new ImageSlider({'sliders':'TickerHorizontal','transitionduration':6000});
```

Html looks like

```
<div id="TickerHorizontal">
<ul>
<li>.....</li>
<li>.....</li>
<li>.....</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The script works well in both sliding and stopping on mouse over BUT I'm struggling in adding buttons to move forward and backward manually

Any suggestion?

Comment: Ok, found a great Mootools gallery which is making exactly what I need and even more slideGallery 
[link](https://github.com/ginger/slideGallery)

Comment: So remove or close this question :)

Comment: I'd like to keep it as I think it's interesting for other people as well... Not sure I know how to close the question :-(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a great Mootools gallery which is making exactly what I need and even more:
https://github.com/ginger/slideGallery